# Is there an HTML5 tag to signify an article preview?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

The description for an article element read:

> The article element represents a component of a page that consists of
>   a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site
>   and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable,
>   e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or
>   newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an
>   interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of
>   content.

However, I'm interested in showing a preview of some content that will be wrapped in an article element. It isn't the article itself, but is a link to the article and contains *some* of the content. Is there a semantic way of expressing this in HTML5, or would divs be appropriate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best HTML5 tag to use for marking up blog excerpts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501834/whats-the-best-html5-tag-to-use-for-marking-up-blog-excerpts)

Answer (score 5):

There is no HTML5 tag specifically for preview excerpts.

Arguably, a summary of an article is a self-contained, potentially-reusable/syndicate-able bit of content, so you’d probably be fine using [`<article>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-article-element.html#the-article-element) for it.

Otherwise, `<div>` is always fine, although you might consider `<section>` or a list depending on the context.

To mark up the actual preview text, you could use [`<blockquote>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-blockquote-element.html#the-blockquote-element), as you’re quoting the article.

Answer (score -2):

`nav` may be come handy, but it risks becoming overkill, as it creates a section in the outline. One may also consider using `figure`, especially if the excerpt also has a thumbnail.