# Can each article element have it's own nav?

Tags: html, nav, semantic-markup

I'm thinking of this front page layout where "the main navigation" is spread out all over the page, with the latest article from each category displayed, like this:

```
<article>
    <nav><a href="/elephants">Elephants</a></nav>
    <h2><a href="/elephants/borneo.htm">The Borneo Elephant</a></h2>
<p>...</p>
</article>
<article>
    <nav><a href="/hippos">Hippos</a></nav>
    <h2><a href="/hippos/malgasy.htm">The Malgasy Hippo</a></h2>
<p>...</p>
</article>
<article>
    <nav><a href="/rhinos">Rhinos</a></nav>
    <h2><a href="/rhinos/white.htm">The White Rhino</a></h2>
<p>...</p>
</article>
```

Would that be semantically correct?

Comment: The article's content should be inside the `<article>` tag... It seems like you are using the tag to indicate the link is a hyperlink to an article which is semantically incorrect IMHO.  Either you have an article or you have a navigational aid.  There is nothing wrong with each article having its own navigational aid (to navigate within the article, I suppose) but the current format just seems wrong (without further explanation as to your reasoning behind it)

Comment: Actually they're excerpts (updated the code for clarity) and it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969153/is-there-an-html5-tag-to-signify-an-article-preview) and elswhere that it would be fine to use <article> for excerpts.
Else there would be no "article" on the front page anyway... I don't mind that but wouldn't know what to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `article` element contains a `nav` element, this `nav` represents the navigation for this `article`. This could be used for an article’s table of contents, or for a pagination in case the article is split into multiple pages.

Your example doesn’t make much sense, and its outline is a mess and not really clear/usable:

```
1. implied heading from <article>
  1.1 implied heading from <nav>
2 "The Borneo Elephant"
3. implied heading from <article>
  3.1 implied heading from <nav>
4. "The Malgasy Hippo"
5. implied heading from <article>
  5.1 implied heading from <nav>
6. "The White Rhino"
```

If this really is your site’s navigation menu, you should use *one* `nav`.

However, there is no obvious solution for adding an excerpt for each navigation item’s last article (it’s a rather uncommon way, I’d guess). These are usually two separate sections, i.e., a `nav` for the navigation, and a `section` for the recent articles:

```html
<nav>
  <!-- <h1>Navigation</h1> -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/elephants">Elephants</a></li>
    <li><a href="/hippos">Hippos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/rhinos">Rhinos</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <h1>Recent articles</h1>

  <article>
    <header>Category: <a href="/elephants">Elephants</a></header>
  </article>

  <article>
    <header>Category: <a href="/hippos">Hippos</a></header>
  </article>

  <article>
    <header>Category: <a href="/rhinos">Rhinos</a></header>
  </article>

</section>
```

Assuming that you can’t separate these sections: it would probably not be clear for users that this excerpt only represents one (i.e., the latest) article of that category/section; so you probably add some explanation to this anyway, so maybe using a section for each navigation menu item could work, e.g.:

```html
<nav>
  <h1>Navigation</h1>

  <section>
    <h2><a href="/elephants">Elephants</a></h2>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2><a href="/hippos">Hippos</a></h2>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2><a href="/rhinos">Rhinos</a></h2>
  </section>

</nav>
```

Inside each `section`, you could add the excerpt, e.g., by introducing it with another heading in a `section`:

```html
  <section>
    <h2><a href="/elephants">Elephants</a></h2>
    <section>
      <h3>Newest "Elephants" article</h3>
      <article>
        <!-- excerpt -->
      </article>
    </section>
  </section>
```

or just by adding some text:

```html
  <section>
    <h2><a href="/elephants">Elephants</a></h2>
    <p>Newest "Elephants" article:</p>
    <article>
      <!-- excerpt -->
    </article>
  </section>
```

But I would advice *against* all this (mixing the navigation with the list of newest articles) and go with separate sections (as in my first snippet).

Comment: Actually it's not that uncommon, lots of newspapers and magazines are organized like that (not too intensive on html5, though, most are just using divs all over). There can be even more than one article per section, like the latest 3 or 5 or somethning. And the "nav" would serve as some sort of mini-breadcrumb (or full, where there is enough space).
But I do get the point that the outline gets messed up, creating lots of sections for all the small bits of taxonomy and that a less obtrusive element might serve better.

Comment: @LucianDavidescu: Do you know an example for such a site? I’m not sure I understand the "mini-breadcrumb" part. I would have imagined that such "recent article" lists *don’t* represent the site’s (main) navigation.

Comment: Indeed, most have a "main navigation" as well, but that one I don't want to use at all. What I'm talking about is showing just the latest piece from each category, such as here: http://www.newyorker.com/

Comment: @LucianDavidescu: I see. I consider this to be part of the article’s metadata (like the tags of a blog post), so I would mark it up like the first example in my answer: an `article` with the link to the category in a `header`; not using `nav`. (And like they do it on newyorker.com, too, using Schema.org’s [`articleSection`](http://schema.org/articleSection) property for this, if you want to use Schema.org.)