# Which html5 Tag Should i Use for Sidebars?

Tags: html, tags

I was about to use the "aside" tag, but it's not for sidebars apparently.

So, what HTML 5 tag should I use for a sidebar that would contain links of related articles, last posts added and popular posts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best HTML5 markup for sidebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407805/best-html5-markup-for-sidebar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Best HTML5 markup for sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407805/best-html5-markup-for-sidebar)

But since your sidebar is presenting a collection of links to other pages, I would go for `<nav>`

More: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-html5/

Comment: I think `<nav>` is a poor choice for a sidebar. From the [HTML5 spec for `nav`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-nav-element.html#the-nav-element): "Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element — the element is primarily intended for sections that consist of **major navigation blocks**. In particular, it is common for footers to have a short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of service, the home page, and a copyright page. The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element can be used in such cases, it is usually unnecessary."

Comment: I agree with @steveax here, nav is a bad choice for this, aside would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<aside></aside>` for sidebar.

For more HTML5 references see [w3school's HTML5 tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp).

Comment: not a good idea according to this article, check "Incorrect use of <aside>"
http://html5doctor.com/understanding-aside/

Comment: The article mentioned has since been superseded and <aside> is now recommended; http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/