# Sidebar navigation: which tag is semantically correct?

Tags: html

I have a sidebar with navigation links in a template I am building for an admin 
dashboard, something like:

```
<aside>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
<main>
 ...
</main>
```

I wonder if using an `<aside>` tag was semantically correct, or should I use `<nav>` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best HTML5 markup for sidebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407805/best-html5-markup-for-sidebar)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is for navigation, use [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

> The *HTML `<nav>` element* represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.

---

Compare against [`<aside>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside), which does not mean what you think it means;

> The *HTML `<aside>` element* represents a section of the page with content connected tangentially to the rest, which could be considered separate from that content.

So, `<aside>` means more *"side note"* rather than *"side bar"*.

---

If you wanted, you could use `<aside>` to section the side bar then a `<nav>` inside it to contain the navigation links

Comment: My nav is certainly not something tangential!) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside
>   element, and which could be considered separate from that content.
>   Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography. [html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/understanding-aside/)

And

> Do not use the  element to tag parenthesized text, as this kind
>   of text is considered part of the main flow. **Mozilla**

Here is the best simple example about how to use `aside`:

```
<article>
  <p>
    The Disney movie <em>The Little Mermaid</em> was
    first released to theatres in 1989.
  </p>
  <aside>
    The movie earned $87 million during its initial release.
  </aside>
  <p>
    More info about the movie...
  </p>
</article>
```

Before, I saw HTML structure of some popular websites like Spotify, they are using `div` for their sidebar. But if you like to read more, you should take a look at [Best HTML5 markup for sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407805/best-html5-markup-for-sidebar)

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stick to nav cause this is the only navigation I plan to have in the template.

Comment: @Deka87 You are welcome. Good, I also think iit is better to go standard way which is nav