# html5 semantics for "next post"

Tags: html, semantics, element

I'm struggling with som html5 elements.
Let's say I have a blog post. 
Next to it I have a preview of the next blog post. What html5-element would you recommend? On the one hand, it's a `<nav>` but it could easily be a `<aside>` or even an `<article>` (because I give a short preview). What d you use/think?

Comment: Hope this will help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501834/whats-the-best-html5-tag-to-use-for-marking-up-blog-excerpts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [What's the best HTML5 tag to use for marking up blog excerpts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501834/whats-the-best-html5-tag-to-use-for-marking-up-blog-excerpts)

Using a `<blockquote>` is the best.